# Building a two DC motor robot cart with rpi

Tags: gpio, hardware

I want to build a Robot which runs on Two DC motors have cart like structure , I want to control it using PWM. what is best way to do it directly from rpi without using Arduino or kits or modules but only using Driver ICs and components ? The control should precise enough and should not damage the rpi
(like unregulated voltage or when motor is rotated should not act like a generator and destroy my rpi)
what are the components i should use and how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way without modules would be using a self contained driver chip like the L293 or L293D from Texas Instruments.  http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/l293d.pdf

The L293 will need additional back EMF protection in the way of fly-back diodes which are included in the L293D.

As long as your motors are suitable (say 5-30V, 500mA each) then you don't need any other components.

Each chip will drive two motors independently forward or reverse and you can use PWM to control the speed.

The Pi can provide suitable PWM without additional components.

As to how, there must be hundreds of L293/L293D based tutorials on the www.